# Can players at other locations play multiple cards to help you in combat?

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

A player using Kyra didn't have a weapon or spell in his hand to help defeat the Hill Giant that came up during his Explore action. Valeros, in a separate location, played a Shortbow and a Heavy Crossbow to add two dice to the combat check.

Is this allowed? The rules state you *can't play more than one card of the same type during a check*; Kyra's player's argument was that it should be allowed, because it technically wasn't Valeros' combat check.

Comment: Why would it make a difference who's check it is?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. That's why I asked. Technically, Valeros isn't making a check, and both cards say that they can add to a combat check.

Comment: Re "Technically, Valeros isn't making a check". Again, why do you think this is worth mentioning? The rule you quoted doesn't say anything about who is making the check. You seem to think that somehow contradicts the rule, but you say you don't know why when asked??

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, I'm not sure whether or not the rule is being contradicted here. That's why I thought it was worth mentioning; the combat check isn't for Valeros, so I was wondering if that rule still applied. Let me specify:  the rule I quoted applies to the character who is having the encounter. I assumed that was a given, so I didn't include it in the question. I'll edit it, as I now see that it's pertinent information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After thoroughly searching, I think I found the answer in the [FAQ's](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gk#v5748eaic9ral) about encountering cards:

> Each player may play no more than 1 card of each type during each step; for example, no one player may play more than 1 blessing while attempting a check, though multiple players could each play 1 blessing during that check.

So in other words, no. Valeros could play 1 weapon to help, but not two. The rule is regardless of who is having the encounter.